# Google Analytics Android device Real Time overview showing 0

Tags: android, google-analytics

So I'm trying to implement Google Analytics in my mobile application.

I have added this `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'` to my dependencies inside the build.gradle file.

This is my app class:

```
public class app extends Application {

private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-xxxxxxxx-x";

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

}

public enum TrackerName {
    APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
    GLOBAL_TRACKER
}

HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(30);

        analytics.setDryRun(false);

        analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.INFO);

        Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
        if(t != null)
        {
            t.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
        }
        mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

    }
    return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
}
```

In my activity I then have this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    // Get tracker.
    Tracker t = ((app)   getApplication()).getTracker(app.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    t.setScreenName("StartActivity");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
}
```

With this my analytics page shows no user at all when I test the application on my phone. Does it take time to show up (I only set up the new account for the application in my analytics panel a few hours ago)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If your Analytics property was recently created it might take a while before you start seeing real time data.

Comment: yes I created it around 24 hours ago now. Any ideas how long it takes?